# Path variables in Spring WebSockets @SendTo mapping

Tags: java, spring, websocket, stomp, sockjs

I have, what I think to be, a very simple Spring WebSocket application.  However, I'm trying to use path variables for the subscription as well as the message mapping.

I've posted a paraphrased example  below. I would expect the `@SendTo` annotation to return back to the subscribers based on their `fleetId`.  ie, a `POST` to `/fleet/MyFleet/driver/MyDriver` should notify subscribers of `/fleet/MyFleet`, but I'm not seeing this behavior.

It's worth noting that subscribing to literal `/fleet/{fleetId}` works.  Is this intended?  Am I missing some piece of configuration?  Or is this just not how it works?

I'm not very familiar with WebSockets or this Spring project yet, so thanks in advance.

**Controller.java**

```
...
@MessageMapping("/fleet/{fleetId}/driver/{driverId}")
@SendTo("/topic/fleet/{fleetId}")
public Simple simple(@DestinationVariable String fleetId, @DestinationVariable String driverId) {
    return new Simple(fleetId, driverId);
}
...
```

**WebSocketConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/live");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/fleet").withSockJS();
    }
}
```

**index.html**

```
var socket = new SockJS('/fleet');
var stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
stompClient.connect({}, function(frame) {
    // Doesn't Work
    stompClient.subscribe('/topic/fleet/MyFleet', function(greeting) {
    // Works
    stompClient.subscribe('/topic/fleet/{fleetId}', function(greeting) {
        // Do some stuff
    });
});
```

**Send Sample**

```
    stompClient.send("/live/fleet/MyFleet/driver/MyDriver", {}, JSON.stringify({
        // Some simple content
    }));
```

Answer (score 140, accepted):

Even though `@MessageMapping` supports placeholders, they are not exposed / resolved in `@SendTo` destinations. Currently, there's no way to define dynamic destinations with the `@SendTo` annotation (see issue [SPR-12170](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-12170)). You could use the `SimpMessagingTemplate` for the time being (that's how it works internally anyway). Here's how you would do it:

```
@MessageMapping("/fleet/{fleetId}/driver/{driverId}")
public void simple(@DestinationVariable String fleetId, @DestinationVariable String driverId) {
    simpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSend("/topic/fleet/" + fleetId, new Simple(fleetId, driverId));
}
```

In your code, the destination '*/topic/fleet/{fleetId}*' is treated as a literal, that's the reason why subscribing to it works, just because you are sending to the exact same destination.

If you just want to send some initial user specific data, you could return it directly in the subscription:

```
@SubscribeMapping("/fleet/{fleetId}/driver/{driverId}")
public Simple simple(@DestinationVariable String fleetId, @DestinationVariable String driverId) {
    return new Simple(fleetId, driverId);
}
```

**Update:**
In Spring 4.2, destination variable placeholders are supported it's now possible to do something like:

```
@MessageMapping("/fleet/{fleetId}/driver/{driverId}")
@SendTo("/topic/fleet/{fleetId}")
public Simple simple(@DestinationVariable String fleetId, @DestinationVariable String driverId) {
    return new Simple(fleetId, driverId);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @sergi!  I was hoping to get around using the MessagingTempalte, but that works just as well.  What is the difference between using `@SubscribeMapping` and `@SendTo`?  Does the former just skip the message broker?

Comment: `@SubscribeMapping` intercepts only subscriptions (not messages to the channel), return value will be sent directly to the user, but can be overridden with `@SendTo` to send it to another destination (will be forwarded to the brokerChannel). `@SendTo` can also be used with `@MessageMapping` to send the response to a specific destination. So basically, `@SendTo` can be used along with `@MessageMapping` and `@SubscribeMapping`

Comment: i'm to do same project equals, but can't start, same has prototype project can use, in github for example. I'm know work Spring but not work WebSocket, i'm need send message two person and, the message same equal Skype. one to one, tree if invite more one user comunications

Comment: Thanks for your updates on this answer it was really helpful!

Comment: Hello @SergiAlmar, is there a way to accomplish the same thing without using stomp? We are comtemplating using plain websockets to do provide streaming data to dynamic endpoint, something like /path/{id}

Comment: @SergiAlmar do you know of any example projects that use the variable placeholders? Not sure about the rest of the configuration to achieve this.

Comment: @JordanMackie check https://github.com/salmar/spring-websocket-chat/blob/c77467a77905abc24100d4e8040158c450d12a79/src/main/java/com/sergialmar/wschat/web/ChatController.java#L54

Comment: @myspri no, if you use a raw WebSocket you won't have any application protocol, so you'll have to implement it

Comment: @SergiAlmar the line "@MessageMapping("/chat.private.{username}")" is there anything stopping other users listening on this endpoint? i.e. if I have the username jmack, I can still access /chat.private.someoneelse? Also - Just realised I watched your talk on websockets this morning! Loved it!

Comment: @JordanMackie that destination is only used to send private messages, but not for receiving them. I use a user destination (just for that user) to receive messages, please read the docs on user destinations https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#websocket-stomp-user-destination

Comment: @SergiAlmar I have read them, my current issue is trying to set up something like multicast groups with websockets where one user publishes and many users listen. All I can find in the docs and examples are one-to-one private communication and broadcasting.

Comment: @JordanMackie you can broadcast the message and the secure the destination with Spring Security https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/websocket.html. If that's not enough, implement a channel interceptor with your own security.

Answer (score 1):

Actually I think this is what you might be looking for:

```
@Autorwired
lateinit var template: SimpMessageTemplate;

@MessageMapping("/class/{id}")
@Throws(Exception::class)
fun onOffer(@DestinationVariable("id") id: String?, @Payload msg: Message) {
    println("RECEIVED " + id)
    template.convertAndSend("/topic/class/$id", Message("The response"))
}
```

Hope this helps someone! :)

Answer (score 0):

you can send a variable inside the path. for example i send "este/es/el/chat/java/*" and obtaned in the server as "este:es:el:chat:java:*"

client:

```
stompSession.send("/app/chat/este/es/el/chat/java/*", ...);
```

server:

```
@MessageMapping("/chat/**")
@SendToUser("/queue/reply")
public WebsocketData greeting(Message m,HelloMessage message,@Header("simpSessionId") String sessionId) throws Exception {
    Map<String, LinkedList<String>> nativeHeaders = (Map<String, LinkedList<String>>) m.getHeaders().get("nativeHeaders");
    String value= nativeHeaders.get("destination").getFirst().replaceAll("/app/chat/","").replaceAll("/",":");
```