# Multiple rooms in Spring using STOMP

Tags: spring, websocket, stomp, spring-websocket

Is it possible to create rooms with STOMP and Spring 4? Socket.IO has rooms built in, so I'm wondering if Spring has this

My code at the moment:

```
@MessageMapping("/room/greet/{room}")
@SendTo("/room/{room}")
public Greeting greet(@DestinationVariable String room, HelloMessage message) throws Exception {
    return new Greeting("Hello, " + room + "!");
}
```

It would be ideal to have @SendTo("/room/{room}")

however, I am limited to:

```
@SendTo("/room/room1") 
@SendTo("/room/room2")
@SendTo("/room/room3")
```

etc...which is VERY VERY unideal

The client is:

```
stompClient.subscribe('/room/' + roomID, function(greeting){
    showGreeting(JSON.parse(greeting.body).content);
});
```

where roomID can be room1, room2, or room3...
What If I want more rooms? It feels like such a pain right now

Answer (score 42, accepted):

It looks like this "room" feature is actually a publish/subscribe mechanism, something achieved with topics in Spring Websocket support (see [STOMP protocol support and destinations](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.1.4.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/websocket.html#websocket-stomp-overview) for more info on this).

With this example:

```
@Controller
public class GreetingController {

  @MessageMapping("/room/greeting/{room}")
  public Greeting greet(@DestinationVariable String room, HelloMessage message) throws Exception {
    return new Greeting("Hello, " + message.getName() + "!");
  }

}
```

If a message is sent to "/room/greeting/room1", then the return value Greeting will be automatically sent to "/topic/room/greeting/room1", so the initial destination prefixed with "/topic".

If you wish to customize the destination, you can use `@SendTo` just like you did, or use a MessagingTemplate like this:

```
@Controller
public class GreetingController {

  private SimpMessagingTemplate template;

  @Autowired
  public GreetingController(SimpMessagingTemplate template) {
    this.template = template;
  }

  @MessageMapping("/room/greeting/{room}")
  public void greet(@DestinationVariable String room, HelloMessage message) throws Exception {
    Greeting greeting = new Greeting("Hello, " + message.getName() + "!");
    this.template.convertAndSend("/topic/room/"+room, greeting);  
  }

}
```

I think taking a quick look at [the reference documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.1.4.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/websocket.html) and some useful examples, such as a [portfolio app](https://github.com/rstoyanchev/spring-websocket-portfolio) and a [chat app](https://github.com/salmar/spring-websocket-chat) should be useful.

Comment: This might also be useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27047310/path-variables-in-spring-websockets-sendto-mapping/27055764#27055764

Comment: any chance the rest of your source is available elsewhere? I'm just wondering what other configuration is necessary to make this work.