# PathVariables in Spring WebSockets @SubscribeMapping not working

Tags: java, spring, websocket, stompjs

I am trying to something similar to this "[Path variables in Spring WebSockets @SendTo mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27047310/path-variables-in-spring-websockets-sendto-mapping/27055764#27055764)"
But I want to send a table name as additional information to **@SubscribeMapping("/topic/data").**
"tablename" can be anything based on my need(what I want to set), it should concatenate **@SubscribeMapping("/topic/data/{tablename}")** and on the server side, I would like to access the tablename to get the data from the database. I have tried the solution mentioned in the above post lien @DestinationVariable but I think I am missing something.

Comment: Finally I figured out myself. Needed to add similar details on the server side

Answer (score 2, accepted):

on the server side :

```
 @SubscribeMapping("/getviewschema/{tablename}")
 public JSONObject getViewSchema(@DestinationVariable String tablename) throws Exception
 {
     DataManager manager = new DataManager();
     return manager.getViewJSONSchema(tablename);
 }
```

On the client side

```
socket.stomp.subscribe("/app/getviewschema/"+service.tablename,function(data) 
{
        listenerview.notify(JSON.parse(data.body));
});
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer, it actually works. I missed it in the docs, it was here: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.x/spring-framework-reference/web.html#websocket-stomp-handle-annotations