# Spring framework web sockets unique @SendTo annotation

Tags: java, spring

I have a web app that has registered users and i would like to push messages to users who have unique user ids. To be able to send a message to the clients, i need to know how to pass unique user id in the `@sendto` annotation

This is the annotation

```
@SendTo("/topic/uniqueuserid")
    public Greeting greeting(HelloMessage message) throws Exception {
        int uniqueuserid;
        Thread.sleep(1000); // simulated delay
        return new Greeting("Hello, " + message.getName() + uniqueuserid "!");
}
```

and this the stomp js

```
stompClient.subscribe('/topic/uniqueuserid', function (greeting) {
            showGreeting(JSON.parse(greeting.body).content);
        });
```

How can i pass a unique user id in `@SendTo("/topic/uniqueuserid")`

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27047310/path-variables-in-spring-websockets-sendto-mapping

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `@DestinationVariable` annotation in a method argument, like that:

```
@MessageMapping("/mychat/{uniqueUserId}")
@SendTo("/topic/{uniqueUserId}")
public Message message(@DestinationVariable("uniqueUserId") Long uniqueUserId, HelloMessage message) {
    logger.info("Unique user id: {}", uniqueUserId);
}
```